# Is there a tool that combines zcat and cat transparently?

Tags: text-processing, cat, compression, gzip

When handling log files, some end up as gzipped files thanks to `logrotate` and others not. So when you try something like this:

```
$ zcat *
```

you end up with a command line like `zcat xyz.log xyz.log.1 xyz.log.2.gz xyz.log.3.gz` and then with:

```
gzip: xyz.log: not in gzip format
```

Is there a tool that will take the magic bytes, similar to how `file` works, and use `zcat` or `cat` depending on the outcome so that I can pipe the output to `grep` for example?

NB: I know I can script it, but I am asking whether there is a tool out there already.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try it with `-f` or `--force`:

```
zcat -f -- *
```

Since `zcat` is just a simple script that runs

```
exec gzip -cd "$@"
```

with long options that would translate to

```
exec gzip --stdout --decompress "$@"
```

and, as per the `man gzip` (emphasize mine):

```
-f --force
      Force compression or decompression even if the file has multiple links
      or the corresponding file already exists, or if the compressed data is
      read from or written to a terminal. If the input data is not in a format
      recognized by gzip, and if the option --stdout is also given, copy the
      input data without change to the standard output: let zcat behave as cat.
```

Also:

> so that I can pipe the output to `grep` for example

You could use `zgrep` for that:

```
zgrep -- PATTERN *
```

though see Stéphane's comment below.

Comment: Note that both `zless` and `zgrep` are scripts that do call `gzip -cdfq` (that is `zcat -fq`).

Answer (score 45):

`zless`

It seems a pity about `zcat`, as libz has an API that supports reading from both compressed and uncompressed files transparently.  But the manpage does say that `zcat` is equivalent to `gunzip -c`.

Answer (score 13):

I use exactly for the same purpose:

```
{ cat /var/log/messages ; zcat /var/log/messages*.gz ; }| grep something | grep "something else" ....
```

Comment: I like this approach because, it requires the least time spent on educating co-workers. If the log messages have a timestamp in a sort-friendly timestamp, this is especially useful.

Answer (score 9):

There is a drop-in replacement for ztools (zcat, zgrep, ..) called zutils that unites all the decompression tools independently of the backend. So with the same command you can read plain, lzma, gzipped, xz files transparently.

It's available in debian wheezy or newer, probably in redhat/centos too.

The project's page is here [nongnu.org](http://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html)

A blog post explaining the usage of the util here ([noone.org](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/CoolTools/zutils.html))

Answer (score 3):

This works fine in RHEL 5.x where zcat is a binary.  It fails in RHEL 6.x (and Ubuntu 12.x) where zcat is a script.  This *used* to work fine.

I wouldn't be using zcat at all but zgrep won't properly handle uncompressed files either.

Answer (score 3):

Opens both compressed and non-compressed, in chronological order.

```
ls -v syslog* | tac | xargs zcat -f | less
```

Comment: It gives wrong order with more than ten log files (syslog.10.gz ...)

Comment: Good catch. -v should fix that.

Comment: `ls -rv` to avoid `tac`.  For log files, `less $(ls -rv syslog*)` with your `LESSOPEN` env var set properly works well.  You can do search across files with `esc-n` to find next match, ignoring file boundaries.

Comment: With `zsh`: `zcat -f syslog*(nOn)`

Comment: This doesn't work if you have your log rotate set to compress the next day

Answer (score 2):

What about wrapper?

```
$ cat xcat.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@;do 
        [ ! -z "$(file -i $i | grep "gzip")" ] && zcat $i || cat $i
done

$ bash xcat.sh plain.txt gzipped_text.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Ryan's answer, the following will get the get all the 'rolled' files sorted alphabetically, then get the current file, uncompress them, if needed, and `less` them:

`cat <(ls mylog.log-* | sort) <(ls mylog.log) | xargs zcat -f | less`

or if you want to get them all as a continuous stream, you can `tail` them, and optionally pipe that to another process

`cat <(ls mylog.log-* | sort | xargs zcat -f) <(tail -f -n +0 mylog.log)`

I should note that this is designed for logs that are rotated daily with the date appended to the end of the file. If your logs us a different format, you'll have to modify the first part of the `cat` statement to accommodate.

Answer (score -1):

There is a beautiful perl script exacly doing this. It's logresolvemerge.pl from the awstats project: http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_tools.html

Logresolvemerge allows you to get one unique output log file, sorted on date, built from particular sources:

It can read several input log files

It can read .gz/.bz2 log files

The output is on STDOUT, so that you can utilize it quite nicely in additional processes.