# How to obtain the chronological list of package upgrades in debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

I would like to obtain the chronological list of package upgrades. Something like:

```
Jan 08 10:45:33 CET 2016  xorg 1:7.7+6      upgrade to 1:7.7+7
Jan 10 13:16:33 CET 2016  gcc 1.132         upgrade to 1.133
Jan 12 07:05:33 CET 2016  pulseaudio 5.0-12 upgrade to 5.0-13
```

I'm interrested in the upgrade list on my machine but also on the debian sources.

Comment: The closest you're going to get without a custom script are the files in `/var/log/apt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be found in the file `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Use this command to generate a list:

```
awk '$3=="upgrade"' /var/log/dpkg.log*
```

Example output:

```
2015-12-30 15:33:15 upgrade firefox 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 43.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

Comment: The log files are not correctly concatenated. The `*` will order log files from most recent to older and inside a file the lines are ordred from older to most recent.

Comment: The fix for that is to either sort the files (e.g. `$(ls -rt1 /var/log/dpkg.log*)` instead of the glob, or (more reliable) to sort the output (ISO-8601 dates sort well naively).  A bigger issue is that your logrotate rules may (like mine) gzip the older files...

Comment: For the compression problem see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77296/is-there-a-tool-that-combines-zcat-and-cat-transparently

Answer (score 0):

I adress two issues in [chaos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52727/chaos) answer:

1) The generated log file is not ordered because `*` will log files alphabeticaly (`dpkg.log`, `dpkg.log.1`, `dpkg.log.2`, ...) which is equivalent to from most recent to older, and inside a log file, lines are ordred from older to most recent. One solution is (thanks [Toby](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112566/toby-speight)) to use `ls -rt`

```
awk '$3=="upgrade"' $(ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log*)
```

2) The files in /var/log could be gzipped by logrotate. For this the following answer is useful : [Is there a tool that combines zcat and cat transparently?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77296/is-there-a-tool-that-combines-zcat-and-cat-transparently). The solution is

```
 zcat -f -- $(ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log*) | awk '$3=="upgrade"'
```